# how can I name this blob?

Tags: firebase, blob

After croppin the image with cropperjs, I create this blob and then upload it to firebase storage. The problem (i think) is that all the new files have the same name. So when the app makes a fetch() to display these images, only the last file uploaded shows up. The other ones are there, but no image is being shown.

```js
function handleCropImage() {
            cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 524,
                heigth: 524,
                imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
                imageSmoothingQuality: 'high'
            })
            .toBlob((blob) => {
                blobResult.value = blob)
            }, 'image/jpeg')
        }
```

So, I can I assign a new name to the blobs? I couldn't find the solution... It seems like such a simple thing to do.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

After hours of seraching, I just tied something: I simply did the following:

```js
file = blobResult.value

file.name = Date.now()
```

The solutions to the very simple problems are the hardest to find...